# Android Emulator Commands to call activity after phone boot is completed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have developed and android application which is called after phone boot is completed. Now, for testing it I am using my android phone and every time I have to switch on and off my phone to test it.

Is there any command on for android emulator which switch offs and switch on it. I want to test it on android emulator. Let me know how can I do it.

Comment: In test purposes you can check your code with other Intent Action, then BOOT_COMPLETED. Then, when your code is debugged, return the action back.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such a boot service. Just close the emulator window, and reopen it to test the boot service.

But it's tricky: When you start the emulator window again, be carefull not to use the run button. If you use the run button, the application will be installed again, and the boot service is not active right after installation.

So you need to install the application, close the emulator, and then to open the emulator using the green button in the toolbar. If you can't find this button, just start any other Android project.

Your boot service will now be executed.